# Why Facebook PHP SDK sets access_token to zero when calling getLogoutUrl() function?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
 ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$params = array( 'next' => 'https://localhost);
echo $facebook->getLogOutUrl($params);  
?>
```

But it generates a link with access_token=0 and when I click it, it just goes to Facebook homepage.

Comment: Did you have a valid user access token before?

Comment: yes $facebook->getAccessToken() gives me a valid access token

Comment: Is it a _user_ access token for sure? And btw., in the code you’ve shown (which contains a syntax error, too), you are not even passing the parameters you defined to getLogOutUrl …

Comment: No, I’m asking if the access token the SDK has set internally the moment you are calling the getLogOutUrl _method_ is a valid _user_ access token. (Reason: Logging out requires a valid user access token, because otherwise _any_ site on the web could log me out of Facebook by just redirecting me to the logout URL.)

Comment: Then it’s an app access token, not a user access token.

Comment: now i have a user access token but when i click the link it goes to Facebook homepage again

Comment: Well have you set the `next` parameter correctly this time, and does it match your app’s domain or website domain?

Comment: After returning from the logout URL, try calling the `destroySession` method of the Facebook object.